# A good noun to describe "complex details" of a project/model

Tags: word-request

I've been struggling to find a good word to describe "complex entangled details" of a project.

Example:

> The model is too simple to describe [the complex details] of the project.

What's a good noun there?

Answer (score 2):

I would go with

> The model is too simple to describe **the complexity** of the project.
>
> The model is too simple to describe **the perplexity** of the project.

Comment: Nice, Andrew. I'm not sure about the second one, however. I don't think *perplexity* is used to convey that meaning much our lifetimes. Otherwise, could you provide any examples? I would also advise the OP to consider some different verbs, although they do ask for nouns: too simple to capture; too simple to account for . . ..

Comment: @JimReynolds I am very curious to know how you would say "too simple" differently

Comment: Hmmm . . . I think it would depend on context. A mathematician, statistician, data scientist writing a paper for expert readers would probably phrase it differently than someone who is speaking or writing informally and/or in a less specialized or academic context. I think *too simple* works well enough for many situations. Maybe just *is inadequate to* . . . *is insufficiently athletic to* gets a bit fancy, but might be nice. *is not sophisticated enough to . . .*?

Comment: In data science, one speaks of the **capacity** of a model: "The model lacks the capacity to describe the complexity of the project."

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **intricacy**, the noun related to the adjective *intricate*.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intricate) says:

> COMPLEX, COMPLICATED, INTRICATE, INVOLVED, KNOTTY mean having confusingly interrelated parts. COMPLEX suggests the unavoidable result of a necessary combining and does not imply a fault or failure: `a complex recipe`. COMPLICATED applies to what offers great difficulty in understanding, solving, or explaining: `complicated legal procedures`. INTRICATE suggests such interlacing of parts as to make it nearly impossible to follow or grasp them separately: `an intricate web of deceit`. INVOLVED implies extreme complication and often disorder: `a rambling, involved explanation`. KNOTTY suggests complication and entanglement that make solution or understanding improbable: `knotty ethical questions`.